control scale/size of plots
I am using corrplot in RStudio to produce plots of various sizes. I want these plots to all have the same scale (i.e. the squares should have the same size).
However, for a given device (either the plot window in RStudio or a PDF device), the plots are always enlarged to the maximum size. This means that for smaller datasets, the text has the same size as for larger datasets, but the squares are larger. See minimal example code below:
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M = cor(mtcars)

#plot 11 x 11 matrix; squares are small
corrplot(M, method = 'circle',order='hclust', diag=F)
#plot 5x5 matrix; squares are large
corrplot(M[1:5,1:5],method = 'circle',order='hclust', diag=F)

How can I ensure this scale remains the same?
NB I know how to specify the size of the PDF device, but this affects the whole plot (including text labels, margins, and legends).
Thanks

Is this from library(corrplot)? Try using mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), with your desired values.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is from library(corrplot) - sorry for not being clear; I've now edited my example accordingly.

I would like to try mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), but am not sure how to calculate the desired values to ensure scaling remains the same? Sorry if this is basic stuff but I am at a loss...

afaik there's no way to keep the squares exactly the same in corrplot. The size of the squares depends on the number of cols/rows of the matrix. If you then take a subset it doesn't know the ratio. Since the right legend bar is also scaled it's rather difficult/impossible to get an exact value.

Is it perhaps possible to specify the plot size instead of the margins? That would already help greatly.
